# enable PHP on windows Apache server

Tags: windows, apache-2.2, php

I need to run a PHP app on a windows apache server. I've installed Apache, unzipped the app into the htdocs folder, but when I type this URL into the browser

```
http://localhost:8080/pixelpost/admin/install.php
```

I get the content of the PHP file, rather than the output it should generate. What are the steps for enabling PHP support in Apache on windows? I guess I need to install mod_php, and possibly do some other stuff, but my Apache and PHP knowledge is minimal, so idiot-proof instructions would be much appreciated.

Thanks,
Don

Answer (score 2):

Follow [these instructions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/install.windows.apache2.php) step by step.